# Oracle SQL - Return modified records, problem with ordering when joining

Tags: sql, oracle, join

I need to return rows for child *p_id* ( parent is *p_id* = 10 and child = 20) which were changed.

I'm using something like below in link, but its ordering incorrectly so I'm getting wrong results. It would be easier to explain on example:

All required data and queries here: [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=78047e89de5f6b4acfc354b0411dc209)

As you can see in results, child and parent rows have mixed order (eg. first row: CHILD_DATE_FROM   = 03/05/2022 and PARENT_DATE_FROM = 08/05/2022 (should be also 03/05/2022))

To clarify (as I cannot explain it better) for this data I need to return results like below (as only these rows have changed)

```
| pl_id | l_id  | date_from  | date_to          |
| ----- | ----- | ---------- | ---------------- |
| 20    | 313   | 10/05/2022 | 10/05/2022 18:21 |
| 20    | 316   | 11/05/2022 | 13/05/2022 04:22 |
| 20    | 316   | 15/05/2022 | 17/05/2022       |
```

Thanks for help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wasn't sure how to tell if a record was changed but looks like something like that?

```
select distinct c.*
from child_gtt c, parent_gtt p
where p.l_id = c.l_id 
and not exists (
  select 1 
  from parent_gtt x 
  where c.l_id = x.l_id 
  and c.date_from = x.date_from 
  and c.date_to = x.date_to);
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=d96a27344adc36045899bda9eaf0ac92)

Comment: I've updated my db<>fiddle link, maybe it will be more clear now.  I've split data into two tables. 
As you can see in gtt inserts, l_id 312 has exactly the same rows in both tables, second row for 313 is also the same. 314 and 315 are not in both tables, so these are exluded (that's correct)
So I need to return three remaining child rows: 1st 313 and both 316 (as these are different from parent)

Comment: I've updated my fiddle link as well. now it returns 1 row for 313 and 2 rows for 316